# Pigpio on callback get value

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, pigpio, python-2.x

I currently have some code that I found that constantly outputs a value from a digital caliper. However, I want to modify this so that it is inside a function that can return that is returned from `show()` after the callback is executed. Is there any way that this is possible?

I have tried global variables with no success.

I currently have this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# caliper.py
# 2015-10-03
# Public Domain

import time

import pigpio

CLOCK=21
DATA=20

g_level=0
g_reading=0
g_bits=0

def show(bits, value):

   inch = value & (1<<23)
   minus = value & (1<<20)

   value = value & 0xfffff

   if inch:
      reading = value / 2000.0
      units = "in"
   else:
      reading = value / 100.0
      units = "mm"

   if minus:
      sign = "-"
   else:
      sign = ""

   print("{} {:.3f} {}".format(sign, reading, units))

def cbf(g, l, t):
   global g_level, g_reading, g_bits
   if g == DATA:
      if l == 0:
         g_level = 1
      else:
         g_level = 0
   elif g == CLOCK:
      if l == pigpio.TIMEOUT:
         if g_bits > 10:
            show(g_bits, g_reading)
            g_reading=0
            g_bits=0
      elif l == 0:
          g_reading = g_reading | (g_level<<g_bits)
          g_bits += 1

pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.set_mode(CLOCK, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_mode(DATA, pigpio.INPUT)

cb1 = pi.callback(DATA, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
cb2 = pi.callback(CLOCK, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
pi.set_watchdog(CLOCK, 20) # 20 ms reading timeout

time.sleep(120)

cb2.cancel()
cb1.cancel()
pi.stop()
```

Is there anyway that this is possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear if the code in your question works or not.  Does it correctly show the caliper value?

Comment: @joan yes it does

Answer (score 0):

You could add a global last_reading and adjust show as follows.  Then whenever you want the last reading just print last_reading.

```py
last_reading = ""

def show(bits, value):
   global last_reading
   inch = value & (1<<23)
   minus = value & (1<<20)

   value = value & 0xfffff

   if inch:
      reading = value / 2000.0
      units = "in"
   else:
      reading = value / 100.0
      units = "mm"

   if minus:
      sign = "-"
   else:
      sign = ""

   last_reading = "{} {:.3f} {}".format(sign, reading, units)
```

Comment: Would this mean keeping the loop but waiting, say 1/2 sec for it to wait and read `last_reading` outside the loop?